# What is the history of this coin? By Mandate of Heaven) Emperor of the Great Qin", Nurhaci - 1616-1626

Tags: china, identification, contemporary-history, numismatics

[image: I have this coin want to know who picture on this coin and whats written on this]
I want to know the complete history of this coin.

Comment: FYI the coin is engraved with *(By Mandate of Heaven) Emperor of the Great Qin", [Nurhaci](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nurhaci) - 1616-1626*.

Comment: "the complete history" - do you mean a complete list of who's hands it has passed through and what it was used to purchase?

Comment: got my answer from bellow reply.thanx

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This particular coin is part of a set of [commemorative tokens](http://www.coincommunity.com/forum/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=59592#466378) (aka fantasy coins) made in (modern) China, with a token for each of the Qing Dynasty emperors. This one shows Emperor Nurhaci with the dates when he was in power shown below his likeness on the "coin".

Comment: what will be the price of this coin?

Comment: You mean, what's it worth now? No much. Apparently they're made from a cheap alloy and have a novelty value only. If you have the full set in the commemorative case, it's probably worth a little more to a collector.

Comment: A quick check on e-Bay shows the whole set going for around $16.

Comment: That explains the very modern-looking Arabic numerals (in a western font) on the bottom. That part had me perplexed.